# How do I style a component that has `styled-components` nested in it?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am new to `styled-components`. I'm trying to set styles for `MyComponent` to apply to `styled-component`.

```
export const Relative = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`

export const Container = ({ children }) => {
  return <Relative>
    <AnotherComponent/>
    {children}
  </Relative>
}

export const MyComponent = () => <Container>/* */</Container>
```

How can I use `styled-components` to style a `Container` inside `MyComponent` without editing MyComponent?

Comment: And the backticks in the source are part of the *styled-components* thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `styled(YourComponent)`, assuming YourComponent is a normal Component and not already a styled-component, this will automatically provide the `className` property to the component. You simple need to put that somewhere.

```
export const Relative = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`

export const Container = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Relative>
      <AnotherComponent/>
      {children}
    </Relative>
  )
}

export const MyComponent = ({ className, children }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <Container>
        {children}
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export const CustomMyComponent = styled(MyComponent)`
  // Styles inside here will be applied to the root element of MyComponent
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap Container into another, like:

```
const MyComponentContainer = styled(Container)`
  ...custom styles
`
```

This could also help: *[Styling any component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)*